# Проблема со шрифтами на сайте

Tags: html, css

Я использовал два шрифта похожих на друг друга, Bebas Neune & League Gothic, но почему-то в браузере они выглядят очень коряво и угловато? Почему так может происходить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя должно быть примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что они загружаются при отображении сайта? Открывайте инструменты разработчика в браузере на вкладке сеть и перезагружайте страницу.

Comment: @Visman да уверен просто почему-то не корректно, и да перезагружать страницу в смысле через f5?

Comment: Да, но вкладка сеть в инструментах должна быть открыта, чтобы было видно какие файлы загружаются, какие нет.

Comment: @Visman так я открыл инструменты разработчика у себя на сайте, и где там должна быть сеть?

Comment: @Visman Так нашел сеть и перезагрузил страницу и да как файл оно подгружает на сайт этот шрифт

Comment: Вашу проблему можно увидеть на реальном сайте? Или вы на локалхосте работаете?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67361/discussion-between-brafik-and-visman).

Comment: Шрифт тут явно подгружается, у меня такие проблемы решаются прогоном через https://www.fontsquirrel.com/, более того там есть возможность существенно ужать шрифт выкидыванием ненужных символов.

Comment: Если хотите конкретной помощи выложите [mcve]

Comment: И да код пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Я решил эту проблему, и проблема заключалась не в самом коде. Она заключалась в том что у меня на самом компьютере не была включена функция сглаживания шрифтов, при её включении проблема пропала.